# dtc not found when using buildroot

Tags: arm, buildroot

The error is below:

```
CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dtb
/bin/sh: 1: /home/buildroot-2017.08-rc2/output/build/linux-3.10.100/scripts/dtc/dtc: not found
scripts/Makefile.lib:272: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dtb' failed
make[3]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dtb] Error 12
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: The Linux build system should build dtc when it needs it - this has been the case long before 3.0. Perhaps there is a different error higher up in the log about building dtc?

Comment: As it turns out, i have messed up the configuration. So started over with cleaning. The problem does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dtc/dtc.git    
cd dtc
make
```

Then it works！

If the version is wrong, some errors may occur, like

```
dtc: invalid option -- '@'
```

Maybe you can try a different version.